# why @autowired in spring does not need setter method for private instance variable?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have some code in my spring project as below

```
@Component
public class DatabaseAccessUtil
{
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseAccessor databaseAccessor;
}
```

My concern is how and why @Autowired annotation of spring work without setter method, example:

```
void setDatabaseAccessor(DatabaseAccessor databaseAccessor)
{
    this.databaseAccessor = databaseAccessor;
}
```

where is spring's miracle? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the value of the field is injected via [`Reflection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and [`Constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) are all descendants of [`java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html). This class permits access to its private members by setting the accessible flag to true by calling [`setAccessible(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29).

Here is the actual code from `AutowiredBeanPostProcessor` that does the actual injection

```
if (value != null) {
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    field.set(bean, value);
}
```

And the source code of `ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(Field)`

```
public static void makeAccessible(Field field) {
    if ((!Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) ||
            !Modifier.isPublic(field.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()) ||
            Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) && !field.isAccessible()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }
}
```